# I'm not able to run SonarQube on my project

Tags: python, django, sonarqube

I've installed both sonarqube server as well as scanner and changed the properties file also. But still it's giving the below issue.

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project home must be an existing directory: C:\Django\webapplication\webapplication\Djangowebapplication

I've my project in the C:\Django\webapplication directory.Below is my configuration file for sonar-project.properties file

```
sonar.projectKey=devsonarqube
sonar.projectName=webapplication
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Django\webapplication
sonar.sources=C:\Django\webapplication
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `java properties` files `\` characters need to be escaped with `\\`, e.g.:

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=C:\\Django\\webapplication
sonar.sources=.
```

Note: `/` does not need to be escaped:

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=C:/Django/webapplication
sonar.sources=.
```

Comment: One more question I have. I ran sonar on the project but It's showing Quality gate failed.. Not sure why?